# Auto fitting a cell to the size of the content?

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I'm new to tcpdf, creating my first document.

I wonder if there is a way to fit the width of the cell automatically to the content. I currently only see options for fixed size, or taking the whole page width until the end of the  line.

I'm aware of GetStringWidth() but having the following problems with it

- Why should one bother even for this? Is there a way to just make the cell fit automatically to its contents width?
- GetStringWidth() seems to err from time to time, giving shorter results the actual, thus causing the text to be split to the next line. A font is set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After learning TCPDF more, this is the conclusion:
Cell() and MultiCell() are not intended to be used for just outputting a string and fitting it's length. Instead, Write() and WriteHtml() should be used. Cells exist for the case where you actually want to control the dimentions of the field manually.

Nevertheless, in some cases one may want to compute the width of the cell, such that it takes into account the sizes of the text inside. For this purpose exists GetStringWidth(). (Unfortunately for me it err's from time to time. Maybe I'm not aware of something)

Answer (score 0):

Have an internal "Legacy" application that uses TCPDF to generate a PDF of a checklist. We recently moved from creating a giant string of HTML that described a table, created using the `$pdf->writeHTML($myHTMLString);` method, to using the `MultiCell()` methods.

However, we ran into an issue where some text in a description cell would need to run on to a second line, this threw off our layout. As a fix, we created an if block based on 2 variables, one for the string width the other for the actual cell width. (We had 2 instances where the cell width might vary).

If block example:

```
// Get width of string
$lWidth = $pdf->GetStringWidth(strip_tags($clItem['description']));
// Determine width of cell
$oadWidth = (.01*$width[0])*186;
if ($lWidth < $oadWidth) {
    $cHeight = 3.5;
} else {
    $cHeight = 7;
}
```

We then used the variable created by the if block in the `MultiCell()` like this

`$pdf->MultiCell((.01*$width[0])*186, $cHeight, strip_tags($clItem['description']), 1, 'L', 1, 0, '', '', true);`

We reused the `$cHeight` variable for the height params in the other sibling cells so each row of cells had a uniform height. You could most likely reuse this method with any of the other right functions that have a height parameter in TCPDF. Thanks to @shealtiel for the original reference to `GetStringWidth()`